# How to make a cumulative time plot?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, date-and-time, histograms

So I'm working with this data set where there is just one input(a date and time) per line in a .csv file. I've let Mathematica understand the input using "DateStringFormat".  The time looks like Year-Month-Day-Hour:Minute:Second

How do I go about plotting a cumulative histogram of events occurring (up until 100% at the end) where I have time on the x-axis and percent of events occurred on the y-axis?

Comment: Does each date represent a single event? Is that the only data in the file? Is the data sorted?

Comment: An example of the data and some evidence of what you have tried so far would be helpful

Comment: I suspect you'll want to look up `DateListPlot` and `MapIndexed`

Comment: Hey everyone, sample data looks like "2013-01-01-03:10:02.430"}

Comment: shouldn't Histogram[data, "Log", {"Log", "CumulativeCount"}] work? where data is the total imported set

Comment: @GagandeepAnand I don't think `Histogram` knows how to operate on `DateObject`s that would be returned from `Import` of CSV with a `"DateStringFormat"` option. Add your code to you question from the `Import` line to the `Histogram` line. This way we can see what and how you have tried and offer some help.  Format it properly as well.  A snip of the CSV file would help as well.

Comment: probably you need to convert to `AbsoluteTime` if you want to use `Histogram`.  Do you want interval binning?

Answer (score 3):

synthetic data:

```
 strings = 
   DateString /@ 
   Sort@RandomVariate[ NormalDistribution[AbsoluteTime[Date[]], 10^7],200];
```

Note this date string format is not exactly the same as yours but I think all this will still work.

```
 DateListPlot[MapIndexed[ {#, First@#2} &, strings ], 
    Ticks -> {DateRange[{2013, 12}, {2016, 2}, {{3, "Month"}}], 
       Automatic}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
        DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "Year"}]
```

[image]

make that `MapIndexed[ {#, 100 First@#2/Length@strings} &, strings ]` for "%" ..

If you want the data binned:  ( `DateListPlot` also has some binning options, but it will not look like a histogram bar chart)

```
 Histogram[ (AbsoluteTime /@ strings - AbsoluteTime@strings[[1]] ) // 
   #/(60 60 24) &, Automatic , "CumulativeCount" , 
   AxesLabel -> {"days", "event count"}]
```

[image]

(sorry that plot label should be "days" .. )